# application crash at UIimagepicker allocation and randomly

Tags: ios, iphone

i have used below code application crash unexpectedly when uiimagepicker alloc and init and signal segmentation  11 error

```
NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]
                                           initWithRequest:request
                                       delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
   [connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]
                              forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
   [connection start];
```

1. Jan 7 09:59:42 unknown ReportCrash[3446] : MS:Notice:
   Installing: (null) [ReportCrash] (675.00) Jan 7 09:59:43 unknown
   ReportCrash[3446] : Formulating crash report for process
   NAMFS[3443]  Jan 7 09:59:43 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] :
   (UIKitApplication:com.nafms.app[0x9f70]) Job appears to have
   crashed: Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: I didnt see `uiimagepicker` use in code?

Comment: i have not add here but crash because of this.i think.i will submit crah log.

Comment: Yes you should add crash log,with error.

Comment: Jan  7 09:59:42 unknown ReportCrash[3446] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Installing: (null) [ReportCrash] (675.00)
Jan  7 09:59:43 unknown ReportCrash[3446] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process NAMFS[3443]
Jan  7 09:59:43 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.nafms.app[0x9f70]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: please edit it in question not in comment.